# solitaire shuffle and upper string an asterisk for back cards

Tags: java, bluej

I'm creating a solitaire game. *Where there are 28 value in the elements of array for play area. The play area is in the solitaire format. * And there are 24 value in the elements of array for bank. I loop it but it doesn't works

How can i turn to upside down right triangle (solitaire format) the elements on the array? With shuffling it. 
*And also how to turn the upper strings an asterisk that stands for the back of the cards.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int row, space, column;
 //declaring 52 cards for solitaire
String[] cards = { "A@", "A#", "A$", "A&",  "2@", "3@", "4@", "5@", "6@",
                   "7@","8@", "9@", "10@", "K@", "Q@", "J@", "2#", "3#", "4#",
                   "5#", "6#", "7#", "8#","9#", "10#", "K#", "J#",  "2$" , 
                   "3$", "4$" , "5$", "6$" , "7$", "8$" , "9$", "10$" , "K$", "Q$", "J$",
                    "2&" , "3&", "4&" , "5&", "6&" , "7&", "8&" , "9&", "10&" , "K&", "Q&",
                   "J&", "Q#" };

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(cards);

Collections.shuffle(list);

//looping for solitaire format
for(row=1;row<=28;row++)
{
     for(String alpha : list){
    for(space=28;space>=row;space--)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for(column=1;column<=row;column++)
    {

        System.out.print("  " +alpha);

    }

    System.out.print("\n");
```

Comment: When saying "it doesn't work(s)" it's best to explain clearly what you want to happen, and how it differs from what is actually happening.  Perhaps step through your code with a debugger, line by line, and see where it starts to diverge from the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yeah. I mean  My code doesn't form into upside down right triangle like in solitaire format.

Comment: But the shuffle works. I can't apply the shuffle into loop.

Comment: @ChristianLumugdan Hi Christian, welcome to StackOverflow! Here at SO, we like to have a thorough description of the EXACT problem you are experiencing. Saying "It doesn't work" does not help us identify the true nature of your problem, making it very difficult to provide specific solutions! Please update your question with the error you are receiving as well as specific output/results expected.

Comment: What is "upside down right triangle like in solitaire format"?

Comment: @EvanBechtol Thanks. The exact problem is i can't make the format of solitaire or the upside down right triangle. I'm creating a solitaire game.
*Where there are 28 value in the elements of array for play area. The play area is in the solitaire format. 
* And there are 24 value in the  elements of array for bank. 
I loop it but it doesn't works,

Comment: @Warkst Like, the first column 1 elements in array (1 card), second  column  2 elements in array (2 card), third column 3 elements in array (3 cards)  and so on to seventh column where there 7 elements in array (7 cards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each "card" occupies one row, then your problem is you want 7 rows with an decreasing number of columns in each row (7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2+ 1 = 28 cards) - not 28 rows.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] cards =
        { "A@", "A#", "A$", "A&", "2@", "3@", "4@", "5@", "6@", "7@", "8@", "9@",
            "10@", "K@", "Q@", "J@", "2#", "3#", "4#", "5#", "6#", "7#", "8#",
            "9#", "10#", "K#", "J#", "2$", "3$", "4$", "5$", "6$", "7$", "8$",
            "9$", "10$", "K$", "Q$", "J$", "2&", "3&", "4&", "5&", "6&", "7&",
            "8&", "9&", "10&", "K&", "Q&", "J&", "Q#" };

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(cards);

    Collections.shuffle(list);
    final int columns = 7;
    final int rows = 7;
    int card = 0;

    // loop over rows
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        // Fill empty columns in this row
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        // Add #columns - row# cards to this row
        for (int j=i; j<columns; j++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(card++) + "\t");
        }
        // advance to next row
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, you may want to look over a [glossary of solitaire terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Patience_terms) to better describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yup Like that, but how to turn the upper strings to an asterisk. Asterisk will stands for the back of the card.